# Apache LocationMatch match group and use in a header

Tags: apache-2.4, http-headers

I am trying to get a pattern from an URL, and to use it in a header.

Something like

```
<LocationMatch "^/static/(?<sitename>[^/]+)">
 Header set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "frame-ancestors 'none'; report-uri https://csp-reporter.com/%{env:MATCH_SITENAME}"
</LocationMatch>
```

As documented [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#locationmatch)

I am getting an error

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line XXX of XXX/httpd.conf:
Unrecognized header format %
```

We are using Apache 2.4.46

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if I remember correctly, I had a similar error and it was because I had forgotten the always...
Header **always** set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "frame-ancestors...

Comment: Thanks for you response! I should have mentionned, it works fine if I remove `%{env:MATCH_SITENAME}`

Comment: you are using apache version 2.4.46 and the directive is for apache 2.4.8 min wouldn't be the problem?   From 2.4.8 onwards, named groups and backreferences are captured and written to the environment with the corresponding name prefixed with "MATCH_" it'is in your link  [link]https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#locationmatch[/link]

Comment: Isn't 2.4.46 > 2.4.8? Latest is 2.4.48 https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: nop 2.4.46<2.4.48 right?

Comment: The documentation states `From 2.4.8 onwards`, so I expect it to work with 2.4.46